# Appending data in single line by removing junk character

Tags: shell

I have data in particular format, Where my data is breaking with the lines after a + character and I need in a single line

### INPUT:

```
   ABC|def|ghi+
   |jkl|mno
   XYZ|pqr|lmn+
   |qrr|stv
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
ABC|def|ghi|jkl|mno
XYZ|pqr|lmn|qrr|stv
```

Comment: Are you just looking to delete occurrences of '+\n'?  `sed '/+$/{N; s/+\n//;}'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technique with awk:

```
awk '/\+$/ {printf "%s", substr($0, 0, length($0)-1); next}; 1' file
```

For lines that end with a plus, print the line (minus the plus) without a newline.
For other lines, print with a newline.

Comment: Hi glenn ,
Thansk for the solution:
If you dont mind can you brief me the logic portion that has been mentioned within the AWK